# Jena ARQ adding update request element

Tags: jena, arq

I am working on an extension in Jena, where I have to add new Update element similar to [UpdateModify](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/sparql/modify/request/UpdateModify.html) but the logic is different and I do not want to extend UpdateModify. The [UpdateVisitor](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/sparql/modify/request/UpdateVisitor.html) interface does not have a visit method for the new element. What would be a suitable way to proceed in this case?
Create an interface which extends [UpdateVisitor](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/sparql/modify/request/UpdateVisitor.html), add my new element's visitor method, in that case I have to rewrite all the other update instances which implements this newly extended interface. Is this a good way to implement this?

Comment: If you can't subclass `UpdateModify` then you can change `UpdateVisitor` to add your new Update element. (It is a feature of the visitor pattern in general that the visitor interface is closed.)